# WiFi Extender using Belkin and Axess-tel routers

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a dual band Belkin N600 router. Due to it's location (which cannot be moved), it's not able to broadcast the wifi signal to our entire house. I have an axess-tel MV440 router which is from back when we had cellular wifi. I am wondering if there is a way to use that to pick up the wifi signal from the Belkin router and "extend" the signal to other areas of our home?

Comment: Have you thought about using a Universal WiFi Range Extender, Repeater that works over power line?  I've got the same same situation and was able to resolve it by using [TP-LINK TL-WPA4220KIT](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00HSQAIQU?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you will be able to use the MV440 router (or any other router) to extend the wireless. However, there are 'wireless extenders' that are designed to sit in an 'OK' signal strength area of your house and re-broadcast the signal on one or both bands. They are actually quite cheap - for instance the TP-Link 300Mbps Universal Wi-Fi Range Extender (see [link](http://uk.tp-link.com/products/details/cat-10_TL-WA850RE.html)).

The other approach is to use a powerline adapter which will broadcast a second (separate) wireless network from anywhere else in your house. That is, I think, what the comment above is suggesting.